# Выводит ошибку Module not found: Can't resolve '@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/css/all.min.css'

Tags: node.js, npm

Module not found: Can't resolve '@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/css/all.min.css' in '/home/*****/Рабочий стол/hcms/src/assets/scss'
Установил сначала npm install --save font-awesome , затем npm install 
В папке hcms/src/assets/scss нету модуля @fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/css/all.min.css .Что делать? Его надо где-то скачивать?

Comment: Вы можете обрашатся на <a href="https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-fontawesome#installation">документацию</a> самого библиотеки.

Comment: а куда это надо прописовать?